# How to share my Java Application

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Okay, so I have made the java application using NetBeans, and I have ran and build it do that way I have a jar file. How do I from here make it to where I can share this with other people and the can install the application onto their computer? Also, a side note I am using a MacBook Pro if that makes a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my program, written in Java, usable to other people?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533433/how-do-i-make-my-program-written-in-java-usable-to-other-people)

Comment: If you already have a .jar file, you can just send that to the people you want to share it with- all they'll have to do is double click to open it and it'll work!

Comment: Sorry I did a search for my question I did not see it, but I will look a bit harder next time, thanks!

Comment: Just adding this as a reference because it explains things fairly well: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Answer (score 0):

You could send the `projectname.jar` file to other computer and execute with command

`java -jar projectname.jar`

If you have some difficult check the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

OR

**First:**
Check if the other computer have JDK installed with command `java -version` and `javac -version`

**Second:**
if everything is ok, share your source file *"projectname.java"*, than execute `javac projectname.java && java projectname`, don't forget to do this inside the source folder

**Exemple:**
If my source file was on my Desktop, i type `cd Desktop` and than the commands `javac` and `java`

Don't forget, you need run the file that contains **main**!!!

Good Luck!

**EDIT:**

Follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm_-mnDKAjo

Than, change the icon with right click the exe file, select Properties and click the "Change Icon" button adding the icon that you want.

Comment: Is there a way to share it and them open as a program like you would with Microsoft word?

Comment: Like a icon on my desktop that i click and open the program?

Comment: Yeah that would be more of what I am looking for Filipe Filardi

Comment: I never used something like that, gonna do a research and came back, but the icon cannot be the projectname.jar itself?

Comment: No I want it to be an app that people can run on their computers like Microsoft word program

Comment: I edit my answer, could you please try the edit steps!?

Answer (score 0):

Much better to create installation package. See this link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html#se

Answer (score 0):

Share Source code (.java) through svn or git. If you want easy public access, I can suggest a cloud service like GitHub.  Share binaries through a dependency management tool like maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point here is that 'Microsoft Word' is a native Windows executable, and Java programs are not.

Microsoft Word is written in C++ and compiled by a Windows C++ compiler to a native Windows executable format which Windows recognizes and will run if you double click on the icon on the desktop.

Java programs run on the JVM (Java Virtual Machine). If you download and install the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) on Windows, you can then run Java programs in the JVM by typing `java -jar myProgram.jar`

There are tools that can wrap your .jar file in a native Windows .exe, you might like to look at:

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

and specifically the Docs page:

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

which shows how to specify the configuration file. Once you have a configuration file setup, you can run:

```
launch4jc.exe config.xml
```

to spit out your new myProgram.exe file that you can distribute.